# Copy/Paste not working for WoW installed through Battle-net

Tags: world-of-warcraft, battle.net, wine, lutris

System:

Ubuntu 22.10
Wine version: lutris-fshack-7.2-x86_64 (but any other wine version I have tried has the same problems)
Lutris 0.5.11
I installed Battle.net through lutris website.

Steps to take:

Launch Battle-net
From inside Battle-net, launch World of Warcraft
Expected:
Copy/paste functionality works.

Actual:

Cannot copy/paste from/into World of Warcraft.

Strange:

Can copy/paste from/into Battle-net without problems.

This affects not only World of Warcraft. but any game I launch from Battle-net.

I can run other EXEs directly into my prefix, and I can copy/paste fine (like notepad)

If I run WoW directly rather than through Battle-net, it has the same problem (no copy/paste capable).